# Files are not getting deleted after retract of a sharepoint solution

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint solution (empty solution with a feature and event receiver).
When i deploy the solution, it adds folders in layouts/styles folder.
When i retract, the folder is not getting deleted.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Usha

Answer (score 0):

this can vary with endless reasons of sharepoint thinking there is still some need for the files.

try using "Remove Solution", and make sure files are not checked out, or where ever used by the designer.

if you want to be sure delete them from the designer, and then install and remove the solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually created the folder directly inside the layouts folder by any chance ?

Then try deleting the same folder from the layouts folder on the drive itself and then re-deploy the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt really understand what is causing the issue in leaving the folders behind by not deleting after retract of the solution.
So i decided to add a line of code to delete the folder after retracting the solution.
Thanks every one for your responses and sorry for the delay in answering.

Thanks and Regards
Usha